# Change imported SVG Component color with state

Tags: reactjs, svg, fill, react-component

I'm trying to dynamically change an imported SVG color based on a state.

I created my **SVG** component this way:

```
import { ReactComponent as LeftLed }  from './left_led.svg';
```

My component is used this way:

```
<LeftLed className="device_preview_led">
    <path className="path" />
</ LeftLed>
```

And here is my issue. I would like to apply a `style={{fill:this.state.b_color}}` property to one of my component, but it doesn't apply any visible effect on my `LeftLed` component.

It would work on the `<path>` but this one is dynamically generated ( so my own `<path>` disappears ) and I have no idea how to 'fill' it's color. Using a `<img>` instead of a component doesn't allow filling.

How can I change my SVG color dynamically?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

in your case:

`<LeftLed fill={this.state.b_color} className="device_preview_led">`

and make sure your .svg file has `fill` property as:
`<svg fill="current" ... </svg>`

(note that `fill` is applied directly to `<svg>` tag and not as a style or class)